# 14.04 BIOS, ACPI Errors in dmesg

Tags: acpi, dmesg

I recently upgrade from 12.04 x64 to 14.04.1 x64
Dell Latitude Laptop

I am seeing messages in dmesg that are causing me concern.  The 2 excerpts below are the ones I am most concerned with:

```
[    4.804950] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[    4.804961] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    4.804963] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    4.829044] [drm] Wrong MCH_SSKPD value: 0x16040307
[    4.829047] [drm] This can cause pipe underruns and display issues.
[    4.829048] [drm] Please upgrade your BIOS to fix this.
```

and this:

```
[    6.724294] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input13
[    6.724363] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    6.724426] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[    6.724432] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    6.724435] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[    6.724440] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    6.724441] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[    6.724446] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.VID_.GPSP 2 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[    6.724449] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    6.724451] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[    6.724454] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.VID_.GPSP 2 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[    6.724457] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    6.724459] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
```

UPDATE:  Regarding the BIOS message, I did in fact update my BIOS and that resolved the issue.

Still looking for help on the ACPI warnings, if someone can point me in the right direction. ....

Comment: No answer for 5 months, eh?  I guess there's no help for me either.

Comment: No and I have not found a resolution myself.  Still looking for it (though I've back-burnered it for the past few months).

Comment: Can it be related to https://askubuntu.com/a/852442/20275 ?