# ACPI BIOS Error (Bug) on Dell XPS 8940

Tags: 20.04, uefi, bios, acpi

Latest BIOS for the Dell XPS 8940 and I am on Ubuntu 20.04. The following messages are shown in `dmesg`:

```
[    8.663080] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20200528/nsarguments-59)
[    8.903041] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.903045] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.903048] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.903049] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.903049]   Arg0:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.903052]   Arg1:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.903053]   Arg2:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.903054]   Arg3:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 10 52 44
[    8.903056] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.903233] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.903235] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.903236] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.903237] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.903237]   Arg0:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.903239]   Arg1:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.903240]   Arg2:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.903240]   Arg3:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 20 52 44
[    8.903242] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.903418] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.903420] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.903421] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.903421] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.903422]   Arg0:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.903423]   Arg1:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.903424]   Arg2:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.903425]   Arg3:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 30 52 44
[    8.903427] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.903602] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.903604] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.903605] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.903605] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.903606]   Arg0:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.903607]   Arg1:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.903608]   Arg2:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.903609]   Arg3:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 40 52 44
[    8.903611] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.903786] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.903787] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.903789] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.903789] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.903789]   Arg0:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.903791]   Arg1:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.903792]   Arg2:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.903793]   Arg3:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 50 52 44
[    8.903795] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.903970] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.903971] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.903973] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.903973] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.903973]   Arg0:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.903975]   Arg1:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.903976]   Arg2:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.903977]   Arg3:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 60 52 44
[    8.903978] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.904153] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.904155] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.904156] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.904156] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.904157]   Arg0:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.904158]   Arg1:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.904159]   Arg2:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.904160]   Arg3:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 70 52 44
[    8.904162] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.904336] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.904337] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.904339] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.904339] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.904339]   Arg0:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.904341]   Arg1:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.904342]   Arg2:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.904343]   Arg3:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 80 52 44
[    8.904345] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.904520] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.904521] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.904523] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.904523] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.904523]   Arg0:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.904525]   Arg1:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.904526]   Arg2:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.904527]   Arg3:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 90 52 44
[    8.904529] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.904702] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.904704] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.904705] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.904705] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.904706]   Arg0:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.904707]   Arg1:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.904708]   Arg2:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.904709]   Arg3:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 A0 52 44
[    8.904711] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.904885] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.904887] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.904888] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.904888] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.904889]   Arg0:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.904890]   Arg1:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.904891]   Arg2:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.904892]   Arg3:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 B0 52 44
[    8.904894] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.905069] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.905070] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.905071] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.905072] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.905072]   Arg0:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.905074]   Arg1:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.905074]   Arg2:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.905075]   Arg3:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 C0 52 44
[    8.905077] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.905263] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.905265] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.905268] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.905268] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.905269]   Arg0:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.905271]   Arg1:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.905272]   Arg2:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.905273]   Arg3:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 D0 52 44
[    8.905275] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.905477] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.905484] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.905486] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.905486] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.905486]   Arg0:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.905488]   Arg1:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.905489]   Arg2:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.905491]   Arg3:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 E0 52 44
[    8.905494] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    8.905683] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    8.905684] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    8.905686] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    8.905686] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    8.905687]   Arg0:   00000000ea4f27c8 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    8.905688]   Arg1:   000000004b8a2b62 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    8.905689]   Arg2:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    8.905690]   Arg3:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 F0 52 44
[    8.905692] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    9.380024] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    9.380032] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    9.380037] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    9.380038] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    9.380039]   Arg0:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    9.380045]   Arg1:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    9.380047]   Arg2:   00000000e6df3428 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    9.380049]   Arg3:   00000000c3a94cd1 <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 00 4B 56
[    9.380054] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
[    9.380528] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200528/dsfield-184)
[    9.380532] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20200528/dswload2-477)
[    9.380535] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_DSM]
[    9.380537] Initialized Arguments for Method [_DSM]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    9.380537]   Arg0:   00000000c3a94cd1 <Obj>           Buffer(16) 75 0B A5 D4 C7 65 F7 46
[    9.380542]   Arg1:   00000000e6df3428 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000102
[    9.380544]   Arg2:   00000000540edc59 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000010
[    9.380546]   Arg3:   0000000092c4591b <Obj>           Buffer(4) 00 00 50 4F
[    9.380550] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20200528/psparse-529)
```

So far I did not encounter any further problem, just wondering if these error messages should be handled somehow or can be mitigated by some other method I did not yet explore (besides BIOS/UEFI update).

Stephan

Comment: Is my question the same as answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/842134/acpi-warning-argument-4-type-mismatch - please comment.