# NVIDIA drivers - ACPI errors (Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS)

Tags: boot, drivers, acpi, ubuntu-studio, nvidia-geforce

Using NVIDIA drivers `nvidia-driver-530` leads to ACPI errors during startup.
Surely the graphics card does work and the desktop seems to operate flawlessly.
But simply to ignore the errors, feels like ignoring a fire in a base floor, while working in the 20th. (You know the movie "Towering inferno" ?)

What is clear to me:
The problem does not come from the BIOS or the Mainboard manufacturer, because there are no ACPI problems with the `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` driver, but unfortunately this driver is not stable:
Sometimes it does not work at all, sometimes system icons are missing, sometimes it crashes during login ... sometimes the command bars are not visible ... and more.
So I had to change to a stable NVIDIA driver and this is without any doubt the source of the error messages.

BTW: The "recommended" driver is not working at all. After installation, the screen appears as gray background with some pointers on it. Moving the mouse leads to unexpected patterns. A login is not possible.

My question now is:

1. What steps do I need to do, to solve the error messages? (Without to
   supress or to ignore it ... but making the system rock stable.)
2. What is the source of the conflicts?
   (Seems to be conflicts, because of "AE_ALREADY_EXISTS" in the
   messages. Something is doing an operation twice or more ... without
   being able to overwrite or delete it ...)

**Available Drivers:**

```
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-530 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-530-open - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

**Kernel Errors:**

```
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
21.04.23 21:40      ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
21.04.23 21:40  ACPI Error  Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

**My System:**

```
Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-70-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-13700K
Memory: 62.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060/PCIe/SSE2
```

Remark:

In the meantime I found by unstable Situations on the login screen, that the system hangs or freezes. It looks, like the conflicting part of the system has won. The system then can't continue working ...

Comment: Are you using an MSI motherboard by chance?  I get similar messages.  I upgraded from a Z690 Unifiy-X to a Z690 ACE and have had those messages ever since I changed the motherboard.  I see them in 22.10 and 23.04 using Nvidia-driver-525 and Nvidia-driver-530 (only available in 22.10).

Comment: My Motherboard is an `ASUS Prime Z690-A`.
I've tried also with a Linux Mint 21 and Plasma Desktop. I've got the same problem, as soon as I use NVIDIA drivers.
So the problem is NVIDIA specific.

Comment: These ACPI errors are not new.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/842134/acpi-warning-argument-4-type-mismatch  and further discussion links there. Did you have another problem of lockup? More details on that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I am also using Ubuntu 22.04. The issue disappeared after I changed driver from nvidia-driver-530 to nvidia-driver-525-server